# Is it correct to change fields in pre('validate') middleware in mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, middleware, slug

I need to generate slug every time that post get saved into database. Specifficallly on `Post.create` and `post.save`. The single place where I may need this in `PostShema.pre('validate')` middleware like the following:

```
PostSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
   this.slug = sluglify(this.title);
   return next();
});
```

All works fine except the fact that it happens in `validate` middlweare that should only check but not set.

SO my questuin is where should I reside my code for sluglify my title on creating or updating post?

Answer (score 1):

This is not happening in the validation but *before* the validation. IMHO, it 's like if you are prepearing/cleaning your object before validating it; which is OK.

If you feel more confortable with that you could include it in a `pre-save` or `pre-init` instead of the `pre-validate`

Comment: The thing is I don't prepare/clean object but set new field

Comment: So do you thing is it correct to use formatting in `pre('validate')`?